# 84 students are divided into 3 groups of 28...more details

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

$84$ students are going to be equally divided into $3$ different teachers, $A$, $B$ and $C$. $2$ students are both already assigned to $A$. How many possible ways can we assigned the students to teachers?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  First choose $26$ students to go with the $2$ already assigned.  Then choose $28$ for the second class, but are the two other classes distinct or not?

Comment: I made it more specific!

Comment: OK, that saves a division by $2$

Answer (score 0):

Warning: this is almost a complete solution

call the groups a.b and c

the two students are in group a.

Then if we count the number of ways to put the remaining 82 students in groups b and c we are done(because the group a will have to be made up of the ones who where left over). ways to put them in group b is $\binom{82}{28}$ and ways to put them in group c after making group b is $\binom{54}{28}$ so  there are $\binom{82}{28}*\binom{54}{28}$ different way to make the groups leaving that pair of students  in a.

Comment: With the OP's edit, you should not multiply by $3$.